# Are questions asking for specific functions appropriate?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I would like to know a function meeting a few criteria (for instance, an injective multi-variables function). Being not a mathematician, I can not find one myself in a short time.

Is this site the good place for this kind of questions, or do they fall into the *Do my homework* category ?

Comment: IMO, as long as you show that you've done some work before asking your question, it's fine, just like any other homework question. But if your question is a one-liner simply asking "provide function satisfying conditions A B C D", it's less fine.

Comment: In fact, what you're considering less fine is exactly what I have in mind. Do you know if there is any other SE site where this would be acceptable ?

Comment: The worst thing that can happen to you is that if 5 people don't like your question it will be closed. That's not so bad, is it? Take a chance! Might help if you include some motivation, that is, why you want such a function.

Comment: Of course it is fine. And don't worry about showing or not what work you have done on it. It is really not important. Some  people in this site try to enforce it, but it never works, and actually makes the site works worse. You always get your answer anyway. So, go ahead. Even if the question gets closed you can get an answer in the comments.